# Get raw output from tensorflow js model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am working through a simple convolutional network to the MNIST dataset. I want to manually tell the program to go through each step in the process, ie iterate through each Epoch and batch, WITHOUT using model.fit (I want to better understand the inner workings of how tensorflow works).

Currently I have:

```
let EPOCHS = 10;    
let batches = Math.floor(TRAIN_DATA_SIZE/BATCH_SIZE);

      for (let i = 0; i < EPOCHS; i++){
        for (let j = 0; i < batches; i++){
          let inputs = await getNextTrain(BATCH_SIZE,TRAIN_DATA_SIZE, data);

          let inputXs = inputs[0];
          let inputYs = inputs[1];

          let output = await model.evaluate(inputXs,inputYs);
```

to iterate through each Epoch and each batch to traian. However model.evalutate() does not return the output values from the network, only the loss/metrics defined. Is there a specific metric that you can add for this to return the outputs from the network

What I want is the 10 element array (or tensor) that represents what the network thinks the output is for each input (using MNIST so want the probability network thinks each output is the number 0-9)

Comment: `model.predict`?

Comment: model.predict will only give back a tensor that is all 0's except a 1 for the output the model thinks is right. I want to see what all the probabilities are before it selects the one it thinks it is

Comment: It shouldn't. Do you have a layer in your network that sets the max value of it's input to 1 and the rest to zero?

Comment: The final layer is a dense layer, with a softmax activation function. I don't believe that will update it to set the max to 1 and the rest to 0's

Comment: did some more testing, I am farily certain I was just insanely unlucky before where all the outputs were either 1 or so close to 1 I assumed it was a round-off error somehow. Now seeing that there is a spread of outputs from model.predict

Answer (score 1):

You can call model.fit inside your inner loop and setting the following parameters
`epoch=1
initial_epoch=i \\ So that it trains only the current epoch and batch. 'i' being outer loop variable.
x=inputXs
y=inputYs`

This will update all the weights in the model accordingly. You could then call model.evaluate or model.predict or model.get_layer to get the information you would want to see. Since, you have each layer information now, you could check their output values independently by evaluating the particular layer only as required (referring to the line where you mention to see what all probabilities..etc)

With the updated changes :

```
let EPOCHS = 10;
let batches = Math.floor(TRAIN_DATA_SIZE/BATCH_SIZE);

  for (let i = 0; i < EPOCHS; i++){
    for (let j = 0; i < batches; i++){
      let inputs = await getNextTrain(BATCH_SIZE,TRAIN_DATA_SIZE, data);

      let inputXs = inputs[0];
      let inputYs = inputs[1];
      model.fit(..on above mentioned params..);

      model.evaluate() // To get loss and metric values.
      model.predict()  // To the final output of the model for input samples given.
      model.get_layer() //To get info about a particular layer and then retrieve the required info. Refer https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

      // For example to know the 1st layer's output : model.layers[0].output;
```

`

Comment: The thing about this is I specifically do NOT want to update the weights/biases, as model.fit will do. But I am pretty sure model.get_layer() may be what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: I tried to use model.get_layers[0].output, and got the error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Do you have to call one of the other functions beforehand? (Currently only call model.predict before this)

Comment: It is an indicative function. It just demonstrates the process. Refer https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.LayersModel.getLayer  and https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#class:layers.Layer for the exact function names in js.
As an example in js, `model.getLayer(0)`

Comment: Ah okay. In the end, I settled with using model.predict(). The problem was actually with the model I had built, I wasn't creating the weights properly so each all the outputs were essentially 0, so the softmax function was amplifying that to make it so one output had a 1 probability and all others were at 0

Comment: Cool. Hope the answer helped.